# Conditional html in rails forms - a better way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, haml

I have a form with conditional bootstrap:

```
= simple_form_for(@user) do |f|
    = f.input :first_name
    - if f.object.new_record?
      %button.btn.btn-primary{"data-target" => "#accordion", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :type => "button"}
        .fa.fa-cog
        More options
      #accordion.collapse
      = f.input :many_more_fields
    - else
      = f.input :many_more_fields
```

Is there a better way to make only the css conditional, in order not to have to duplicate `= f.input :many_more_fields`.
CSS part:

```
  %button.btn.btn-primary{"data-target" => "#accordion", "data-toggle" => "collapse", :type => "button"}
    .fa.fa-cog
    More options
  #accordion.collapse
```

P.S. Any ideas, except creating a partial for `= f.input :many_more_fields`?

Comment: Why not put the input outside the if condition instead of having an else block